# Nuxt Compiled with warnings - extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm working on a big project that contains multiple files and folders. Now, when I run `npm run dev` or change pages Nuxt is showing this these annoying warnings.

```
 WARN  Compiled with 7 warnings                       friendly-errors 11:11:49


 WARN  Error                                          friendly-errors 11:11:49

chunk pages/add-new-property/index.pages/property/index.pages/room-management/add-new/index.pages/signup/index [extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--16-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/property/policies/yes-no-box.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=67558805&lang=scss&scoped=true&
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--16-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/UI/checkbox/checkbox.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) pages/property/index, pages/room-management/add-new/index
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) pages/add-new-property/index, pages/signup/index
. . .
```

That's just one of the 7 warnings.

Can anyone tell me how to fix or ,at least, ignore those warnings in Nuxtjs? Note that the warnings are from **extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin** not from **mini-css-extract-plugin**.

Edit: This issue only occurs in the development and it's very annoying because when you first load a page the styles aren't loaded. So, you have to manually refresh the page. But after refreshing it, everything's fine if you revisit to that page again.

Answer (score 8):

you can add the **ignoreOrder** property in nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
    extractCSS: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

pages/property/index, pages/room-management/add-new/index
and 
pages/add-new-property/index, pages/signup/index

they both import some components, but the order of the import are different. So you have to check the import order in these files.

For example, file a.vue and b.vue have different import order:

a.vue:

```
import CompA from 'xxx'
import CompB from 'yyy'
```

b.vue

```
import CompB from 'yyy'
import CompA from 'xxx'
```

This will cause the error.

Comment: They have no overlapping imports as far as I can see. They are page components , so, they can't be imported to each other. The errors are showing from  extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin , so, I doubt the imports caused those error. For css codes, I wrote all the css codes inside each components , so, they're also not imported. I think it's the issue of  extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin library.

Comment: Thanks @JerryYu it works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

***For anyone who finds this question...***

So in 2022 I've come across this issue when upgrading a work project to Nuxt 2.15.8 and finding our CSS was not being compiled efficiently at all (inherited project).

It maaaaay be related to an issue with Nuxt and/or extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin which plays havoc with the order of CSS that is built.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4204

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4219

In dev CSS builds in the correct order, in production it does not.

For me it was simply that the order was wrong, regardless of environment.

So I get the warnings reported by the OP but from what I have tested all of my applications CSS is rendering correctly. We're using Vuetify as well, hence why order was so important.

**The configuration that's working for me is;**

**Assets;**

[image: Asset folder file config]

**Nuxt.config.js;**

```
/*
 ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
 */
buildModules: [
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify"
]

/*
 ** Global CSS
 */
css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.scss'
],

/*
 ** Source SCSS
 */
styleResources: {
    scss: [
      '~/assets/scss/extenders.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/mixins.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/variables.scss'
    ]
},

/*
 ** Components auto-load // Nuxt 2.15.8
 */
components: [
    {
      path: '~/components',
      pathPrefix: false
    }
],

/*
** vuetify module configuration
*/
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/scss/variables.scss"],
    treeShake: true,
    ...
}
    
/*
** Build configuration
*/
build: {
    extractCSS: {
      ignoreOrder: false
    },
    ...
}
```

**Main.scss helps to control CSS order;**

[image: Include source files to control CSS order]

**Benefits;**

- Has at least halfed total download
- Home dashboard finished in half the time
- DomContentLoaded: ~2.10s > ~479ms
- Load: ~2.62s > ~802ms